# PHP Script for visit link through another page how?

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP website with a special page.  If a user pastes the URL of my special page in the address bar, I want them to be redirected to my "terms and conditions" page, which will have a link to the special page.

How do I create a redirect like this?

Comment: But that link on your terms and conditions page shouldn't redirect back to the terms and conditions? How would you distinct between pasting the URL and visiting it via another page?

Comment: i want only visitors go on special page only through t&c page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bare minimum version. add submit/post etc. if needed...

terms-and-conditions.php

```
<?php
@session_start(); // @ just in case session started somewhere else
$_SESSION['seen-terms-and-conditions'] = true;
?>
```

special-page.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['seen-terms-and-conditions']) ) { header('Location: terms-and-conditions.php'); die() }
?>
```

remember to call `session_start()` before starting content output.